# YABI: Yet Another Brainfuck Interpreter written in C

Tags: c, interpreter, brainfuck

Syntax is `./bf-interpreter <program.bf>`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MEM_CELL_SIZE 30000
#define MAX_INSTRUCTIONS 5000

unsigned int progressUntilNext(char* source, unsigned int i_pointer, size_t newLen)
{
    int open_brackets = 0;
    for(int i = i_pointer; i < newLen; i++)
    {
        switch (source[i])
        {
            case '[':
                open_brackets++;
                break;
            case ']':
                open_brackets--;
        }
        if (open_brackets == 0)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
unsigned int goBackToPrevious(char* source, unsigned int i_pointer, size_t newLen)
{
    int open_brackets = 0;
    for(int i = i_pointer; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        switch (source[i])
        {
            case '[':
                open_brackets--;
                break;
            case ']':
                open_brackets++;
        }
        if (open_brackets == 0)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned char* memory;
    memory = calloc(MEM_CELL_SIZE, sizeof(char));
    unsigned int memory_pointer = 0;
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Syntax: ./bf-interpreter <filename>\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char* filename = argv[1];
    char* source = NULL;
    size_t newLen = 0;
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp != NULL)
    {
    /* Go to the end of the file. */
        if (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END) == 0)
        {
            /* Get the size of the file. */
            long bufsize = ftell(fp);
            if ((bufsize == -1) || (bufsize > MAX_INSTRUCTIONS))
            {
                printf("Too much instructions\n");
                return 1;
            }
            /* Allocate our buffer to that size. */
            source = malloc(sizeof(char) * (bufsize + 1));
            /* Go back to the start of the file. */
            if (fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET) != 0)
            {
                printf("Seek error\n");
                return 1;
            }
            /* Read the entire file into memory. */
            newLen = fread(source, sizeof(char), bufsize, fp);
            if (newLen == 0)
            {
                fputs("Error reading file", stderr);
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                source[++newLen] = '\0';
                // End of instructions
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("error\n");
            return 1;
        }
    fclose(fp);
    }
    for(int i_pointer = 0; i_pointer <= newLen; i_pointer++)
    {
        switch (source[i_pointer])
        {
            case '>':
                if (memory_pointer == MEM_CELL_SIZE)
                {
                    printf("Memory pointer error\n");
                    return 2;
                }
                memory_pointer++;
                break;
            case '<':
                if (memory_pointer == 0)
                {
                    printf("Memory pointer error\n");
                    return 2;
                }
                memory_pointer--;
                break;
            case '+':
                memory[memory_pointer]++;
                break;
            case '-':
                memory[memory_pointer]--;
                break;
            case '.':
                putchar(memory[memory_pointer]);
                break;
            case ',':
                memory[memory_pointer] = getchar();
                break;
            case '[':
                if (memory[memory_pointer] == 0)
                {
                    i_pointer = progressUntilNext(source, i_pointer, newLen);
                }
                break;
            case ']':
                if (memory[memory_pointer] != 0)
                {
                    i_pointer = goBackToPrevious(source, i_pointer, newLen);
                }
                break;
            case '\n':
                // This is a NOP
                break;
            case '\0':
                return 0;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Not recogized: %c\n", source[i_pointer]);
                break;
        }
    }
    free(source);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed some error checks after memory allocations.
Also you output errors to both `stdin` and `stdout`.
That's not nice.
I guess the only valid use of `stdout` is for Brainfuck `.` command output.
Everything else are errors, they may go to `stderr`.

In C error handling is rather tedious and it is common practice to implement `die` function to terminate program with some message.

Example `die`:

```
void die(const char *msg) {
    fputs(msg, stderr);
    if (msg[0] && msg[strlen(msg)-1] == ':') {
        fputc(' ', stderr);
        perror(NULL);
    } else {
        fputc('\n', stderr);
    }
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Notice how it uses `perror` when `msg` ends with `:`.

`fread` function is a bit tricky.
It returns the number of items read.
If an error occurs, or the end of the file is reached, the return value is a short item count.
One trick is to call it like this: `fread(source, bufsize, 1, fp)`.
This way `fread` will return `1` only if all file was read. Anything else is unexpected end of file or error.

Example `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc != 2) die("Syntax: ./bf-interpreter <filename>");

    FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (fp == NULL) die("fopen:");


    /* Getting file size. */

    if (fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END) != 0) die("fseek:");
    size_t newLen = ftell(fp);
    if (newLen == -1) die("ftell:");
    if (newLen > MAX_INSTRUCTIONS) die("Too much instructions");
    if (fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET) != 0) die("fseek:");


    /* Reading the entire file into memory. */

    char *source = malloc(newLen + 1);
    if (source == NULL) die("malloc:");

    if (fread(source, newLen, 1, fp) != 1) {
        die("Error reading file");
    }

    source[++newLen] = '\0';

    fclose(fp);


    /* Brainfuck interpreter code starts here
       ...
    */
}
```

Some other notes:

- `putchar` and `getchar` can return `EOF`